# ImportError: cannot import name 'Constant' from 'plotly.express'

Tags: python, plot, error-handling, data-visualization, treemap

I've been using treemap to plot some data and according to the main documentary there is something called Constant that you can add to the path of treemap. But unfortunately I couldn't import it or add it to my plot. Here is the code:

```
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant('world'), 'continent', 'country'], 
                 values='pop',color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'])
fig.show()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

**AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'Constant'**

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you post the full error message please? Sometimes this error occurs because there are more than 1 files with same name.

Comment: in my computer it's running fine . Mine is showing the plot even on chrome browser on localhost. `import plotly.express as px` is a latest update. So, may be update your plotly module using pip or something. `pip install --upgrade plotly` . Also, upgrade `pip` too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! Yes, @Tanmaya_Meher after updating plotly it worked perfectly fine!